# in pure asp.net, not mvc3+, invoke controller's methods through routing

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I built a .NET MVC4 Application a few days ago.
The routing module in MVC4 experience was so great and elegant that I would like to implement one of the features into an existing project of my own.

It's pure asp.net 4.0 web project.

The web app is made of pure HTML as view, a lot of javascript and jquery plugins as controllers, and several web services.

It communicates with server, databases, and web services via Ajax.

Every time I try to call a method in a web service, I have to use Ajax, which I had enough.

But implementing routing module into the app hasn't worked so far.

I created `Global.asax` to use route feature at the beginning as below.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

and declared `RegisterRoutes` method as below.

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    name: "loginController",
    //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { controller = "login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapPageRoute(
            "loginController",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            "~/Controller/loginController.cs");
}
```

and created and coded `loginController` like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class loginController : Controller
{
    public string index(int id)
    {
        return "works fine";
    }
}
```

and give it a shot with this url `" http://localhost:52749/login/index/1 "`
then it throws this error page.

```
'/' 응용 프로그램에 서버 오류가 있습니다.

경로 처리기 'System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler'의 GetHttpHandler() 메서드에서 IHttpHandler를 반환하지 않았습니다.

설명: 현재 웹 요청을 실행하는 동안 처리되지 않은 예외가 발생했습니다. 스택 추적을 검토하여 발생한 오류 및 코드에서 오류가 발생한 위치에 대한 자세한 정보를 확인하십시오. 

예외 정보: System.InvalidOperationException: 경로 처리기 'System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler'의 GetHttpHandler() 메서드에서 IHttpHandler를 반환하지 않았습니다.

소스 오류: 

현재 웹 요청을 실행하는 동안 처리되지 않은 예외가 생성되었습니다. 아래의 예외 스택 추적을 사용하여 예외의 원인 및 위치 정보를 확인할 수 있습니다.

스택 추적: 


[InvalidOperationException: 경로 처리기 'System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler'의 GetHttpHandler() 메서드에서 IHttpHandler를 반환하지 않았습니다.]
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9599531
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

My apologies for showing this in Korean.

in a nut shell, it's saying that `GetHttpHandler() Method didn't return IHttpHandler.`

I've tried to google this and haven't picked a clue.

Can anybody help me get out of this??

Comment: When you say "Pure ASP .NET" do you mean web forms?

Comment: Yes it does. fyi, using aspx is exteremly limited here. Not a single one is used for a page. I only use aspx as a service.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "login", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
                  }
```

can you try above?

Comment: @hina10531 have you tried Avinash's solution. It should work if you have MVC installed in your ASP.NET project. If you have tried it, tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: what do you mean by installing MVC in my asp.net? in current environment, Avinash's code doesn't work and it throws 404 error for finding no resources. how can I implement MVC features into my existing asp.net project??? just declaring "using System.Web.Mvc and etc" is enough for my project to be supported by .NET MVC?